# Getting value from custom SeekBarPreference

Tags: android, seekbar, preference

I found this code on internet and thought I would give it a try. I put it in my preferences and it was exaclt the way I wanted it to be but my only problem is that I cant get the value of SeekBar.

Here is the link to code that I am using in my preference:

http://android.hlidskialf.com/blog/code/android-seekbar-preference

and here is the part of preference xml:

```
<com.mypack.SeekBarPreference android:key="zoom"
        android:title="Zoom"
        android:summary=""
        android:dialogMessage="Zoom level"
        android:defaultValue="50"
        android:text=" %"
        android:max="100"
        />
```

can anyone tell me how to get value of seekbar after user has changed it in preferences window?

Comment: This SeekBar has three possible values?

Comment: And how did you include it in your preference? Show us the code?

Comment: edited post, take a look

Comment: are you able to get other preference values? you have working code to do that already?

Comment: well that is my only preference in preference list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use  [setOnPreferenceChangeListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#setOnPreferenceChangeListener%28android.preference.Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener%29):

```
SeekBarPreference mSeekBarPreference = new SeekBarPreference(this, null);
mSeekBarPreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int value = mSeekBarPreference.getProgress();
        // Or you just cast the newValue Object
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you initialize `mSeekBarPreference`?

Comment: Yes, by putting SeekBarPreference mSeekBarPreference;

Comment: @RohitMalish That's defining not initializing! See the update. I gave `null` to `AttributeSet`. Check your SeekBarPreference constructor.

Comment: @RohitMalish If my initialization didn't work then yeah, you should consider that. I'm not familiar with this preference. Take a look at the code of its parent, DialogPreference.

Comment: I guess I'll have to keep searching for easier method to do this, thanks for trying to help

Answer (score 1):

Should be just like any other preference.

implement `SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` in your activity, then:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences( YourActivity.this );
prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener( this );
```

-

```
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged( SharedPreferences prefs, String key ) {
    mZoomValue = prefs.getInt( "zoom", 50 );
}
```