# Show current SeekBarPreference value into ScreenPreference

Tags: java, android, android-preferences, seekbar

what's a good way to show current value of SeekBarPreference into ScreenPreference.
I've tried to insert textview but the app crashes.
Any suggestions?

**preferences.xml**

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <SeekBarPreference
      android:id="@+id/seekbar_pref"
      android:key="seekbar_x"
      android:title="Value"
      android:defaultValue="1"
      android:max="60"/>
  </PreferenceScreen>
```

**Preferences.java**
public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new MyPreferenceFragment()).commit();
}

public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
}
```

**Main.java**

```
private SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener preferenceChangeListener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
            Log.e("SHARED",  "VAL: " + sharedPreferences.getInt("seekbar_x",10));
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `onCreate` method add this line at the end (after adding preferences):

```
SeekBarPreference pref = (SeekBarPreference) findPreference("seekbar_pref");
```

Then add the listener on it like this:

```
pref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

@Override
public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
    int value = mSeekBarPreference.getProgress(); //or (int)  newValue
    //You can now use this value wherever you like:
    pref.setSummary("Value: " + value);
    return true;
}
});
```

Comment: SeekBarPreference pref = (SeekBarPreference) findPreference("seekbar_pref"); i can't import SeekBarPreference, only suggestion is "Create Class ...."

Comment: Uh, same thing happens to me now that I check in Android studio. I don't quite understand how you can use it in the xml and not in code. I found a similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12230975/getting-value-from-custom-seekbarpreference) here on SO. They're using it as a class in Java.

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea. I've never used SeekBarPreference myself. You may have to resort to some other methods before it existed like using regular seekBar and remembering the value manually in SharedPrefs.